# Installing hiredis on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: hiredis

I installed `hiredis` on Ubuntu.

My `redis.conf` file has following lines

```
#unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock
#unixsocketperm 700
```

It was not working. So I changed that to below lines:

```
unixsocket /tmp/redis.sock
unixsocketperm 755
```

While `make test` for hiredis, I am getting the following error

```
Testing against Unix socket connection (/tmp/redis.sock):
Connection error: No such file or directory
Makefile:195: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Comment: The # prefix means a commented line...

Comment: Yes it is a commented line